# Path to same network share differs by machine, can I change path used locally?

Tags: networking, windows-10

We have a server which uses path `\\company.nl\dfs\Something\bla` to connect to a network share. When I try to access the same location from my local machine I have to use `Z:\\bla`.

This is a problem because I want the tests I write to run both locally and on the server. Is there any way to change the mapping locally from `Z:` to `\\company.nl\dfs\Something`?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the full UNC path in both places?

Comment: @EddieDunn you are absolutely right! I thought i had tried that already but i was missing one slash, in apache camel the path becomes file:////company.nl/dfs/Something